# System table in Guidewire and retiring past entries

Tags: guidewire

I have an existing system table and wanted to create in such a way that in future I want to retire them and add new entries going forward.
How can I create it without adding any extra fields like expiration date
#guidewire

Answer (score 2):

Most, if not all system table entities implement the "SimpleEffDated" delegate which adds effective and expiration dates to the entity along with relevant interfaces to insure consistent behavior.  Your custom entity should add that delegate to leverage that ootb feature.

In a related subject you should be careful of declaring FKs that point to the system table.  Have the referring entity reference the system table data by code or a similar key value.  Avoiding a FK avoids "highly shared rows" where one system table row is linked to hundreds or thousands (or more) policies or claims.  This is not an absolute rule, but consider carefully how your system table will be used.  Very often you only need the code or other information from the system table entity stored on your entity, not continual lookups to the source row.